# Widget That Depends on Received Data

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have added a 'subscription' piece to my project, which is set up and works correctly. This piece has a field that contains the year which the subscription is valid for. I wanted to create a new widget that would be able to check if the current user has a subscription that matches the current year, and not show itself if it does not.

I could figure out how to loop through a user's subscriptions and determine if any of them contained the correct year, but I'm having trouble finding a way to pass the current year into the widget to compare with. Is there a recommended way to pass extra data into the widget (in req.data, I assume), or any way to get the current date when building a Nunjucks template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass extra data to a widget from your template like

`{{ apos.singleton(data.page, specialHeader, header, { specialThing: true }) }}`

or

`{{ apos.area(data.page, specialArea, { widgets: { header: { specialThing: true } } }) }}`

and then check `data.options` in your widget's `widget.html` to use it.

You can also create arbitrary JavaScript functions to be used in your Nunjucks templates (referred to as `helpers`). You can read about that here http://apostrophecms.org/docs/technical-overviews/how-apostrophe-handles-requests.html#template-helpers-invoking-synchronous-java-script-code-from-your-template .. this would be an easy place to return the current year.